# After enabling TLSv1.2 in hostapd(an Integrated EAP RADIUS server),"fatal alert:decode error" is received from client(wpa_supplicant) during EAP-TLS

Tags: ssl

I am in a big issue regarding TLSv1.2 and unable to resolve this.

## Scenario:

1. Hostapd should act as an integrated EAP server.I have an openwrt device on which hostapdv2.6-devel is running.
   2.Wpa_Supplicant is acting as a client and should talk to hostapd for successful authentication.wpa_supplicantv2.6-devel is running on a different openwrt device.
   3.Two way SSL handshake(EAP-TLS) should happen successfully and hostapd should authenticate the client device without any issue.
   4.Requirement is that this communication should take place on TLSv1.2 i.e. server (hostapd)is bound to send TLSv1.2.

## Configuration:

### EAP server(hostapd configuration):

1.Since by default server is sending TLSv1.0 to the client so I made it to send TLSv1.2 forcefully by recompiling the package for TLSv12 and install again on the router.
2.Created a configuration file, which has all the server certificate, ca certificate chain eap_server=1 etc.
3.Started the hostapd process on the device successfully.

client configuration(wpa_supplicant):

1.Created a configuration file, which has all client certificate, CA chain, identity, SSID etc.
2.Started the wpa_supplicant on the device successfully.

## SSL transactions:

1.client send client hello message and TLSv1.2 in it.
2.Server responds with server hello message and TLSv1.2
3.Server sends its certificate, serverkeyexchange, certificate request message.
4.Afterward a fatal alert occurs **"decode_error"** and no more transaction are seen and authentication gets failed.

Please see the wireshark capture below.

**ClientHello**
[image: ClientHello]

**ServerHello**
[image: ServerHello]

**Alert Message**
[image: Alert Message]

Kindly help me to resolve this issue as its making my life difficult.
Please let me know if any other information is required.

Thanks.